# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, javascript, json

He estado buscando la solución a este error por todos lados, pero no.

Necesitaria de su ayuda para poder seguir con el proyecto.

He aquí el php  y js.

***PHP:***

```
<?php
    $accion = $_POST['accion'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

    if ($accion === 'crear') {
        # codigo para crear admonistradores

        //hashear password
        $opciones = array(
            'cost' => 12
        );

        $hash_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones);

        //importar la conexion
        include '../funciones/conexion.php';

        try{
            //realizar consulta
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, password) VALUES(?, ?)');
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $usuario, $hash_password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $respuesta = array(
                'respuesta' => $stmt->affected_rows
            );
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();

        }catch(Exception $e){
            //en caso de error, tomar le excepcion
            $respuesta = array(
                'pass' => $e->getMessage()
            );
        }
        print json_encode($respuesta);

        $respuesta = array(
            'pass' => $hash_password
        );

        print json_encode($respuesta);

    }
    if ($accion === 'login') {
        # codigo para loguear 
    }
?>
```

***Y el js:***

```
eventListeners(); 
function eventListeners(){
    document.querySelector('#formulario').addEventListener('submit', validarRegistro);
}

function validarRegistro(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var usuario = document.querySelector('#usuario').value,
    password = document.querySelector('#password').value,
    tipo = document.querySelector('#tipo').value;

    if(usuario === '' || password === ''){
        //la validacion fallo
        swal({
            type:'error',
            title:'Error',
            text: 'Por favor completa todos los campos'
        })
    }else{
        //ambos campos son correctos, ejecutar ajax

        //datos que se envian al servidor


        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append('usuario', usuario);
        datos.append('password', password);
        datos.append('tipo', tipo);

        //console.log(datos.get('usuario'));

        //crear el llamado a ajax
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //abrir conexion - A DONDE ENVIA LOS DATOS 
        xhr.open('POST','inc/modelos/modelo-admin.php',true);

        // retorno de datos

        xhr.onload = function(){
            if (this.status === 200) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            }
        }
        //ENVIAR peticion
        xhr.send(datos);

    }
}
```

Espero que pueda ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: tu JSON no se genero bien, verifica en el inspector del navegador, probablemente tienes un echo o un warning esta haciendo que te de ese error

Comment: A qué se debe que imprimes dos veces la respuesta? `print json_encode($respuesta);`. Qué imprime tu código si sólo ejecutas `console.log(xhr.responseText);`? un error en la respuesta hace que cuando intentas parsearla con `JSON.parse()` se genere una excepción, puede ser que la respuesta esté mal formada o que la respuesta ya sea un objeto json el que no puedes parsear por segunda vez.

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar el json?

Answer (score -1):

Yo también tenía ese mismo error y la solución que encontré fue:

- guardar el archivo PHP como UTF-8 sin BOM (en Notepad++).
- Revisa cómo está guardado tu archivo PHP.